# tooltip stops working after filter action

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-cli

I am applying `bootstrap popover` with `ember cli`. works great but when I use another action to filter the page, the popovers do not work anymore. To bind the popover I'm using the following: 
`views/restaurants/search-results.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
    jqueryEvents: function(){
    Ember.$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  }.observes('controller.filteredRestaurants').on('didInsertElement')
});
```

my `application.js controller` has an action that `transitionsToRoute` `search-results.js` which updates the `filteredRestaurants` property and when it does, the `popover` stops working.

One thing that could be adding complexity is that `search-results template` loops the restaurants that are filtered and each restaurant has a partial with the button that is bound to the tooltip inside the partial for each restaurant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
    jqueryEvents: function(){
       Ember.$('body').on('mouseover', '*[data-toggle="popover"]', function() {
          $(this).popover();
          $(this).popover('show');
       });
    }.observes('controller.filteredRestaurants').on('didInsertElement')
});
```